# Change element location WPF

Tags: wpf, path, pathgeometry

How can I change the location element (Line) in C# code?

```
<Grid x:Name="SetShipsGrid">
        <Path Name="Line" Stroke="red" StrokeThickness="1" >
            <Path.Data >
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="50,50" EndPoint="350,50"></LineGeometry>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just bind the Start and End points to public properties

Xaml:

```
    <Grid x:Name="SetShipsGrid">
        <Path Name="Line" Stroke="red" StrokeThickness="1" >
            <Path.Data >
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="{Binding StartPoint}" EndPoint="{Binding EndPoint}" />
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
```

Code:

```
    private Point _startPoint = new Point(5, 5);
    private Point _endPoint = new Point(100, 100);

    public Point StartPoint
    {
        get { return _startPoint; }
        set { _startPoint = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public Point EndPoint
    {
        get { return _endPoint; }
        set { _endPoint = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In code behind adding a name to the Line:

```
<Grid x:Name="SetShipsGrid">
    <Path Name="Line" Stroke="red" StrokeThickness="1" >
        <Path.Data >
            <GeometryGroup>
                <LineGeometry x:Name="line" StartPoint="50,50" EndPoint="350,50"></LineGeometry>
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

And then in the xaml.cs:

```
this.line.StartPoint = ....
```